# PATH path prefix

Tags: linux, bash

Is there some special path prefix like ~ that denotes "search everywhere in the PATH"? I know so this  is the default behaviour when just executable basename is provided, but with fancy executable name like a=b, I am able to call it only with path, either full or relative like ./a=b. If I provide just basename a=b, bash interprets it as variable assignment.

Comment: Naming your executable like that is clearly not a good idea in the general case.

Comment: But it's a valid question, considering that commands can have weird names that look like syntactic entities, e.g. `[` which is `/usr/bin/test` in disguise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such prefix. You don't need one if your only purpose is to execute a file name with “strange” characters: just quote these characters, e.g. `'a=b'` or `a\=b`. Then bash's parsing and expansion results in the first word of your command being `a=b`, which is looked up in the path like any other command name.

If you want to look up the program in the path but not execute it, use `command -v`. (There are other builtins with the same effect, `command -v` has the advantage of being portable (it's a bash builtin and it's in POSIX). Don't use `which`, it's an external command, unreliable and not portable.)

If you want to look up [all the directories in the path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command) that contain `a=b`, you can use `type -a`.

```
type -aP a=b
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. The best answer so far in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly a prefix, but quoting the executable name (like `'a=b'`) finds it in the PATH for me. (Bash 3.2.17)

Answer (score 1):

The `command` built-in is designed exactly for this purpose, i.e. looking for a command (not an alias, nor a function).

```
command a=b
```

should do the trick. From the bash manual:

> ```
>   command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
>           Run  command  with  args  suppressing  the  normal  shell function
>           lookup. Only builtin commands or commands found in  the  PATH  are
>           executed.   If  the  -p option is given, the search for command is
>           performed using a default value for PATH  that  is  guaranteed  to
>           find all of the standard utilities.  If either the -V or -v option
>           is supplied, a description of command is printed.  The  -v  option
>           causes  a  single word indicating the command or file name used to
>           invoke command to be displayed; the -V option produces a more ver‐
>           bose  description.   If  the -V or -v option is supplied, the exit
>           status is 0 if command was found, and 1 if not.  If neither option
>           is  supplied and an error occurred or command cannot be found, the
>           exit status is 127.  Otherwise, the exit  status  of  the  command
>           builtin is the exit status of command.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use quotes, but another possibility is:

```
(exec a=b)
```